# Reaaciones entre entidades laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos entidades galeria y categoria.

Galería es un Portfolio que va enlazado con una sola categoría

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categoria extends Model
{
    public function galeria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Galeria::Class);
    }
}
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Categoria;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Resizable;

class Galeria extends Model
{
    use Resizable;

    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::Class);
    }
}
```

Quiero sacar un listado de categorias que tengan al menos una galeria.

¿Como lo hago?

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion de Laravel, `belongsTo` es la relacion inversa de `One To Many`, por ende tus modelos no pueden tener la relacion `belongsTo` al mismo tiempo, lo correcto seria que uno tenga `hasMany` y el otro `belongsTo`.

En el contexto del la situacion que planteas (`categoria 1:n galerias`) debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
//Modelo categoria
class Categoria extends Model
{
   public function galerias()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(Galeria::Class);
   }
}
//Modelo galeria
class Galeria extends Model
{
  use Resizable;

  public function categoria()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::Class);
  }
}
```

Laravel tambien menciona que al relacionar los modelos, eloquent determina que las **llaves foraneas** estan escritas de empezando por el nombre de la funcion de la relacion, luego un `_` y finalmente id, para este caso puntual eloquent determinaria que tu **llave foranea** es `categoria_id`. Sin embargo tambien puedes especificar el nombre de la llave foranea en caso de que sea necesario, por ejemplo:

```
public function galerias()
{
  //Esto es solo un ejemplo en el que se especifica el nombre de la llave foranea
  return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::Class, 'idCategoria');
}
```

De esta forma en tus vas a poder acceder a las relaciones de tu modelo de la siguiente forma:

```
use App\Models\Galeria;
//Hacemos una busqueda de la galeria por su id
$galeriaEncontrada = Galeria::find(1);
//Obtenemos a que categoria pertenece
return $galeriaEncontrada->categoria;
```

Por ultimo y lo mas importante, aca esta la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) de laravel para que investigues mas al respecto.